# Hibernate seems to create wrong SQL Query from HQL Query for oracle dialect

Tags: spring, hibernate

While I'm executing a simple select query from HQL I'm getting ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended (select s1_0.id, s1_0.email, s1_0.first_name, s1_0.last_name from Student as s1_0) I know the problem seems to be with the keyword "as" after the table name, though my HQL query is a simple "from Student" I'm confused from where does as keyword is getting appended.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
public class Student {

public Student(){

}

public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
}

@GenericGenerator(
        name = "studentSequenceGenerator",
        strategy = 
 "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
                @Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "STUDENT_SEQ"),
                @Parameter(name = "initial_value", value = "1"),
                @Parameter(name = "increment_size", value = "1")
        }
)

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "studentSequenceGenerator")
private Long id;

@Column(name="first_name")
private String firstName;

@Column(name="last_name")
private String lastName;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
}
```

}

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Student.class).buildSessionFactory();
Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
session.beginTransaction();
List<Student> std = (List<Student>)session.createQuery("from Student").getResultList();
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

```xml
<property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

```
Hibernate: select s1_0.id, s1_0.email, s1_0.first_name, s1_0.last_name from Student as s1_0
Oct 15, 2019 3:01:18 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 933, SQLState: 42000
Oct 15, 2019 3:01:18 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select s1_0.id, s1_0.email, s1_0.first_name, s1_0.last_name from Student as s1_0]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractQuery.list(AbstractQuery.java:1311)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractQuery.java:1328)
    at com.hibernate.demo.ReadStudentDemo.main(ReadStudentDemo.java:29)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select s1_0.id, s1_0.email, s1_0.first_name, s1_0.last_name from Student as s1_0]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.values.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.values.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.values.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.values.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:24)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractQuery.list(AbstractQuery.java:1302)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:494)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:446)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1052)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:537)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:255)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:610)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:253)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:86)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:765)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:921)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1099)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3640)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeInternal(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1384)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3687)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1165)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.values.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:98)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: Error : 933, Position : 73, Sql = select s1_0.id, s1_0.email, s1_0.first_name, s1_0.last_name from Student as s1_0, OriginalSql = select s1_0.id, s1_0.email, s1_0.first_name, s1_0.last_name from Student as s1_0, Error Msg = ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:498)
    ... 28 more
Oct 15, 2019 3:01:18 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PoolState stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
List<Student> students = session.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Student a", Student.class).getResultList();
```

Comment: when you run this in sql developer do you get same error ?
       select s1_0.id, s1_0.email, s1_0.first_name, s1_0.last_name from Student as s1_0

Comment: Yes, it gives me the exact same error but when I remove the "as" keyword from the query it executes.
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 74

Comment: The issue is resolved now, issue was with the Hibernate Jar I did download the development jar once I replaced those jar with the stable version of Hibernate jars everything went smoothly. I appreciate your time and effort.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The Issue was with the development version of hibernate ORM jars once those Jars were replaced by the stable version. Everything went smoothly.
Also, this forum help identified the issue 
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2340268